# How to add a child filed that is not in db in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `school` table. which contains a `parent_school_id` for parent school.

But in form I need to add two filed 1) for parent school 2) for child school.

for parent school it work in entity by following code of entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="parent_school_id",type="integer", nullable=true)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="School", mappedBy="id")
 */
protected $parentSchool;
```

now I add a child school but it is not in db so i added follow code :

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="School")
 * @JoinColumn(name="child_school_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $childSchool;
```

it give me following error ::

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@OneToOne" in property Epx\Bundle\CourseBundle\Entity\School::$childSchool was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

How can I add this extra filed without db field ?

Comment: use @ORM\OneToOne instead of @OneToOne

Comment: `/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="School", mappedBy="parentSchool")
     */
    protected $childSchool;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="School", inversedBy="childSchool")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_school_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $parentSchool;`

Answer (score -1):

It works when I put this code :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="School", mappedBy="parentSchool")
 */
protected $childSchool;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="School", inversedBy="childSchool")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_school_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $parentSchool;
```